# Replace phone number with * in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am very new to Kotlin.
I have a phone number. I want to show only 1st 2 digit and last 2 digit. Rest all I want to replace with *.
98******65.

Can anyone please help me how to do this in Kotlin

Comment: Could the number contain spaces, dashes, brackets, or anything other than digits?  If so, do you want those replaced too?

Answer (score 2):

you can map the characters to * based on index

```
val masked = phoneNumber.mapIndexed { index, c ->
    if (index > 1 && phoneNumber.length - index > 2) "*" else c
}.joinToString("")
```

Comment: @ananya did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
    val number: Int = 12345678
    var numberString = number.toString()
    for (index in 2 until numberString.length - 2){
        numberString = numberString.replaceRange(index, index + 1, "*")
    }
    print(numberString)
```